# PDFBox parser seems to parse, but empty output from text stripper

Tags: android, pdfbox, text-extraction

I have had some problems extracting the text from a document using PDFBox in Android. But the parser seems to be working fine (or at least, that's what I interpret its out to mean; googling "parsed=COSObject" gives no relevant results, unfortunately (for some documents the logcat is spammed and there seems to be no way to turn off this putput)). getCharactersByArticle returns empty output from this document, ie. vectorlistoftps is empty.

I have uploaded the document to: https://ufile.io/cnvoq

For most other documents I have tried, text extraction works fine, or I get errors unrelated to this one. But not here.

Here is the relevant code snippet.

```
private void extractTextPosition() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(var1);
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(stream);

    parser.parse();
    Log.d("Parser has ","parsed");
    StringWriter outString = new StringWriter();
    CustomPDFTextStripper stripper = new CustomPDFTextStripper();
    stripper.setStartPage(currentPage);
    stripper.setEndPage(currentPage);
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

    try {
        stripper.writeText(parser.getPDDocument(), outString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
Vector<List<TextPosition>> vectorlistoftps = stripper.getCharactersByArticle();
}
```

CustomPDFTextStripper is the same as PDFTextStripper (I had changed it, but all of the changes have been commented out).

[Here is the logcat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYdBw.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF in question does not contain any text.

Ok, when you look at it, you see text glyphs but they actually are not drawn using *text drawing commands* (which take strings in some encoding and draw the matching glyphs) but instead each letter glyph is drawn using individual vector graphics operations (move to, line to, curve to, fill, ...).

(You also cannot copy&paste the text in Adobe Reader, you cannot even *mark* it for copying because there simply is no text to mark.)

Text extraction as done by the PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` (or similar text extraction classes of other PDF libraries) only works for text drawn using *text drawing commands* by decoding their string arguments.

Your PDF most likely will require OCR for text retrieval.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that splitting the original document, of which this is just a few pages, had turned the text on its pages into images. I dislike such unpredictable behaviour. I may need a better PDF splitter...

Comment: That is not the natural result of splitting PDFs, it requires work to do this. So this appears to have been a special "feature" of the splitter you used. Indeed, some people want that behaviour because they do not want others to be able to easily extract the text of their pdfs.